# Targetting Boost 32-bit While on 64-bit ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, compiling, boost

Well i have libboost-all-dev installed, but i am trying to compile for 32-bit. I can't install libboost-all-dev:i386 either.

```
g++ -lboost_filesystem main.cpp
g++ -m32 -lboost_filesystem main.cpp
```

The second command throws an error, that boost_filesystem can't be found, but the first one compiles fine. Is there any way around this, or do i have to manually build boost?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for prosperity on bionic:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get -y install g++-multilib libboost-system1.65:i386
```